# What is TRC and DRC in DBMS?

Tags: database, relational-database, relational-algebra, tuple-relational-calculus, domain-calculus

What is *tuple relational calculus (TRC)* and *domain relational calculus (DRC)*? How do they differ with relational algebra?

I am new in DBMS field. But I have learned basics of relational algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In relational algebra, variables contain relations and operators derive relations by transforming or combining relations.
- Relational calculii use set builder notation and logical connectives to define a new relation by describing the tuples and attributes that make it up.
- In tuple relational calculus, variables denote tuples and attributes are referred by name.
- In domain relational calculus, variables denote attributes and tuples are constructed via a positional notation.

Answer (score 1):

**Relational algebra** is procedural language and **Tuple relational calculas** is non-procedural language.
In Tuple relational language we use notations to request the data.

Although **relational algebra** is useful in the
analysis of query evaluation, SQL is actually
based on a different query language.
**Relational calculus** useful to define the semantics
of the relational algebra and SQL

Below is the example(Link between TRC and SQL):

```
TRC = {T | Teaching(T) AND T.Semester = ‘F2000’}
SQL = SELECT *
      FROM Teaching T
      WHERE T.Semester = ‘F2000’
```

Target T corresponds to SELECT list: the query result contains the entire tuple. Body split between two clauses:

- Teaching(T) corresponds to FROM clause
- T.Semester = ‘F2000’
  corresponds to WHERE clause

well in the above answer I would like to add the following line :
The statement above = TRC = {T | Teaching(T) AND T.Semester = ‘F2000’}

can be reffered as
"T is a variable(tuple) whose value is equal to Teaching(T) and T.Semester = ‘F2000’ simultaneously"
ie. T is the tuple from relation "Teaching" and reffers to tuples having attribute "Semester" as ‘F2000’ .

Comment: You have given their features that they are procedural etc..but i need an easy and exact definition...n thanx for answering..

Answer (score 0):

**Domain Relational Calculus**
- In contrast to tuple relational calculus, domain relational calculus uses a list of attribute to be selected from the relation based on the condition. It is same as TRC, but differs by selecting the attributes rather than selecting whole tuples.

**Tuple Relational Calculus**
- A tuple relational calculus is a non procedural query language which specifies to select the tuples in a relation. It can select the tuples with range of values or tuples for certain attribute values etc. The resulting relation can have one or more tuples.